# Math Directory Error

Tags: python, math

I was working on a simple converter, and stored all of the conversion factors in directories. It accepts what to convert from and to, checks to make sure it is convertable, and takes how much needs to be converted and then errors out with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "python", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The code (the alive is just so when finished it won't loop forever):

```
alive = 'yes'
while(alive == 'yes'):
        doable = {'pint': ['cup', 'quart', 'galleon', 'pint'], 'quart': ['cup', 'quart', 'pint', 'galleon'], 'galleon': ['cup', 'quart', 'pint', 'galleon'], 'cup': ['cup', 'quart', 'galleon', 'pint', 'tbsp', 'tsp'], 'ounce': ['cup', 'tbsp', 'tsp', 'ounce', 'ml', 'liter', 'pound', 'gram', 'kilogram'], 'tbsp': ['cup', 'tbsp', 'tsp', 'ounce'], 'tsp': ['tsp', 'tbsp', 'cup', 'ounce'], 'ml': ['ml', 'ounce', 'liter'], 'liter': ['ml', 'ounce', 'liter'], 'pound': ['ounce', 'gram', 'kilogram', 'pound'], 'gram': ['ounce', 'gram', 'kilogram', 'pound'], 'kilogram': ['ounce', 'gram', 'kilogram', 'pound']}
        pint = {'cup': 2, 'quart': 0.5, 'galleon': 0.125, 'pint': 1}
        quart = {'cup': 4, 'quart': 1, 'galleon': 0.25, 'pint': 2}
        galleon = {'cup': 16, 'quart': 4, 'galleon': 1, 'pint': 8}
        cup = {'cup': 1, 'quart': 0.25, 'galleon': 0.0625, 'pint': 0.5, 'tbsp': 16, 'tsp': 48, 'ounce': 8}
        ounce = {'cup': 0.125, 'tbsp': 2, 'tsp': 6, 'ounce': 1, 'ml': 30, 'liter': 0.0295735, 'pound': 0.0625, 'gram': 28.3495, 'kilogram': 0.0283495}
        tbsp = {'cup': 0.0616115, 'tbsp': 1, 'tsp': 3, 'ounce': 0.5}
        tsp = {'cup': 0.020833333, 'tbsp': 0.33333, 'tsp': 1, 'ounce': 0.166667}
        ml = {'ml': 1, 'ounce': 0.033814, 'liter': 0.001}
        liter = {'ml': 1000, 'ounce':33.8, 'liter': 1}
        pound = {'ounce': 16, 'gram': 453.592, 'kilogram': 0.453592, 'pound': 1}
        gram = {'ounce': 0.035274, 'gram': 1, 'kilogram': 0.001, 'pound': 0.00220462}
        kilogram = {'ounce': 35.274, 'gram': 1000, 'kilogram': 1, 'pound': 2.2}
        first = input("What would you like to convert from? ")
        second = input("What would you like to convert to? ")
        if(second in doable[first]):
            amount = input("What is the amount of the first measurement? ")
            conversion = first[second]
            answer = float(amount) * float(conversion)
            print("Your answer is: " + str(answer) + " " + second + "(s).")
        else:
            print("\nYOU CAN NOT CONVERT BETWEEN THESE TWO VARIABLES.")
alive = 'no'
```

Any ideas why it might be erroring and how it can be fixed or another method to avoid the error? Thanks.

Comment: Consider reading the error message, and thinking about what the type of `first` is on line 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first** and **second** are names of units -- they're strings.
What you've asked for in that line is something like

```
"ounce"["gram"]
```

which is nonsense to the run-time system.  There is no element number "gram" of the string "ounce".

I gather that you're trying to allow the user to input the name of a directory variable.  This is severe confusion of functionality in Python.  The string *value* "ounce" is not related to the *variable* **ounce**.

Rather, you have to check to see whether the conversion is "doable".  Then you need to grab the proper conversion factor from the proper directory.

---

**Possible solution:**

Make your conversion table a directory of directories.  Each of your present directories becomes a major heading in this table:

```
conversion = {
    "pint": {'cup': 2, 'quart': 0.5, 'galleon': 0.125, 'pint': 1},
    "quart": {'cup': 4, 'quart': 1, 'galleon': 0.25, 'pint': 2},
    ...
    "kilogram": {'ounce': 35.274, 'gram': 1000, 'kilogram': 1, 'pound': 2.2}
```

Now, you can reference the conversion factor as

```
conversion[first][second]
```

---

**Spelling detail:**

```
"galleon" is a ship powered by oars.
"Gallon" is a unit of measurement.
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help! And thanks for the spelling tip!

Comment: Please remember to up-vote anything you like, and especially to "accept" your favourite answer.  This allows Stack Overflow to archive the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

The line `conversion = first[second]` doesn't work the way you intend it to. `first` is a string. It's not the variable named by that string. To get the variable you'd need to do `eval(first)`, and `eval` is usually a bad idea.

When you find yourself dealing with variable names as data, it usually means you're organizing things wrong. Instead of trying to get the variable by its name, make the name a key into a dictionary.

In this case you already have the appropriate dictionary, `doable`. Rather than having the values of the dictionary be lists of strings (which are the names of other variables), put your other dictionaries inside `doable`:

```
doable = { # you might want to change this variable's name
     'pint': {'cup': 2, 'quart': 0.5, 'galleon': 0.125, 'pint': 1},
     'quart': {'cup': 4, 'quart': 1, 'galleon': 0.25, 'pint': 2},
     #...
     }
```

The problematic code will now become:

```
if second in doable[first]: # this works exactly the same as before
    conversion = doable[first][second] # this gets an extra level of indexing
    #...
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now and is definetly an improvement!